# Irreducible subsets of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: general-topology

Give $\mathbb{C}$ the Euclidean topology. A subspace $A \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is said to be irreducible if and only if $A$ cannot be written as a union of two proper closed (relative to $A$) subsets. I am fairly certain that the only irreducible subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ are the one point sets, but would like confirmation that I am not being silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the set $A$ contains two different points $x$ and $y$, consider their disjoint neigborhoods.

Answer (score 0):

You are right if you have more than or equal to two points then you take the separating closed neighborhoods in $\mathbb{C}$ and intersect with the set to arrive at a union of closed subsets.